# W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 1 of {

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am trying to get the list of names (only) of all nearby places concerning the user's current location, but I am getting the error. when I press the "Show list" button.

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.experimentmaps;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> arrayList;
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

public void onClick(View v){
    try {
        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json? 
location=-33.8670522,151.1957362
&radius=1500
&type=restaurant
&keyword=cruise
&key=AIzaSy***********************_4-M");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView=findViewById(R.id.listview);


    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayAdapter = new 
 ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result ="";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            url = new URL(urls[0]);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            int data = inputStreamReader.read();
            while (data!=-1){
                char current = (char) data;
                result +=current;
                data = inputStream.read();
            }
            return result;

        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);//as s corresponds to result

            String placesinformation = jsonObject.getString("results");

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(placesinformation);

            String placesname="";
            int numberofitems = 20;
            if(jsonArray.length()<5){
                numberofitems = jsonArray.length();
            }

            for(int i=0;i<numberofitems;i++){
                JSONObject jsonpart = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = jsonpart.getString("name");

                if(!name.equals("")){
                    placesname += name;
                }

                if(!placesname.equals("")){
                    arrayList.add(placesname);
                }
            }
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

---

**This is the JSON response i am supposed to get through the above url according to [this](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests)** documentation

```
 {
"html_attributions" : [],
"results" : [
  {
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -33.870775,
           "lng" : 151.199025
        }
     },
     "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/travel_agent- 
 71.png",
     "id" : "21a0b251c9b8392186142c798263e289fe45b4aa",
     "name" : "Rhythmboat Cruises",
     "opening_hours" : {
        "open_now" : true
     },
     "photos" : [
        {
           "height" : 270,
           "html_attributions" : [],
           "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAAF- 
 LjFR1ZV93eawe1cU_3QNMCNmaGkowY7CnOf- 
 kcNmPhNnPEG9W979jOuJJ1sGr75rhD5hqKzjD8vbMbSsRnq_
 Ni3ZIGfY6hKWmsOf3qHKJInkm4h55lzvL 
 AXJVc-Rr4kI9O1tmIblblUpg2oqoq8RIQRMQJ
 hFsTr5s9haxQ07EQHxoUO0ICubVFGYfJiMUPor1GnIWb5i8",
            "width" : 519
        }
     ],
     "place_id" : "ChIJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk",
     "reference" : "CoQBdQAAAFSiijw5-cAV68xdf2O18pKIZ0seJh03u9h9wk_lEdG- 
cP1dWvp_QGS4SNCBMk_fB06YRsfMrNkINtPez22p5lRIlj5ty_HmcNw
cl6GZXbD2RdXsVfLYlQwnZQcnu 
7ihkjZp_2gk1-fWXql3GQ8-1BEGwgCxG-eaSnIJIBPuIpihEhAY1WYdxPvOWsPnb2- 
nGb6QGhTipN0lgaLpQTnkcMeAIEvCsSa0Ww",
     "types" : [ "travel_agency", "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],
     "vicinity" : "Pyrmont Bay Wharf Darling Dr, Sydney"
  },
  {
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -33.866891,
           "lng" : 151.200814
        }
     },
     "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant- 
71.png",
     "id" : "45a27fd8d56c56dc62afc9b49e1d850440d5c403",
     "name" : "Private Charter Sydney Habour Cruise",
     "photos" : [
        {
           "height" : 426,
           "html_attributions" : [],
           "photo_reference" : 
"CnRnAAAAL3n0Zu3U6fseyPl8URGKD49aGB2Wka7CKDZfamoGX2ZTLMBYgTUshjr- 
 MXc0_O2BbvlUAZWtQTBHUVZ-5Sxb1-P-VX2Fx0sZF87q- 
 9vUt19VDwQQmAX_mjQe7UWmU5lJGCOXSgxp2fu1b5VR_PF
 31RIQTKZLfqm8TA1eynnN4M1XShoU8adzJC 
 cOWK0er14h8SqOIDZctvU",
           "width" : 640
        }
     ],
     "place_id" : "ChIJqwS6fjiuEmsRJAMiOY9MSms",
     "reference" : 
"CpQBhgAAAFN27qR_t5oSDKPUzjQIeQa3lrRpFTm5alW3ZYbMFm8k10ETbISfK9S1nwcJVfrP- 
bjra7NSPuhaRulxoonSPQklDyB-xGvcJncq6qDXIUQ3hlI- 
bx4AxYckAOX74LkupHq7bcaREgrSBE- 
U6GbA1C3U7I- 
HnweO4IPtztSEcgW09y03v1hgHzL8xSDElmkQtRIQzLbyBfj3e0FhJzABXjM2QBoUE2EnL- 
DzWrzpgmMEulUBLGrtu2Y",
     "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],
     "vicinity" : "Australia"
  },
  {
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -33.870943,
           "lng" : 151.190311
        }
     },
     "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant- 
 71.png",
     "id" : "30bee58f819b6c47bd24151802f25ecf11df8943",
     "name" : "Bucks Party Cruise",
     "opening_hours" : {
        "open_now" : true
     },
     "photos" : [
        {
           "height" : 600,
           "html_attributions" : [],
           "photo_reference" : 
"CnRnAAAA48AX5MsHIMiuipON_Lgh97hPiYDFkxx_vnaZQMO
 cvcQwYN92o33t5RwjRpOue5R47AjfMltn 
 toz71hto40zqo7vFyxhDuuqhAChKGRQ5mdO5jv5
 CKWlzi182PICiOb37PiBtiFt7lSLe1SedoyrD- 
 xIQD8xqSOaejWejYHCN4Ye2XBoUT3q2IXJQpMkmffJiBNftv8QSwF4",
           "width" : 800
        }
     ],
     "place_id" : "ChIJLfySpTOuEmsRsc_JfJtljdc",
     "reference" : "CoQBdQAAANQSThnTekt- 

UokiTiX3oUFT6YDfdQJIG0ljlQnkLfWefcKmjxax0xmUpWjmpWdOsSc
l9zSyBNImmrTO9AE9DnWTdQ2hY 
7n-OOU4UgCfX7U0TE1Vf7jyODRISbK- 
u86TBJij0b2i7oUWq2bGr0cQSj8CV97U5q8SJR3AFDYi3ogqE
hCMXjNLR1k8fiXTkG2BxGJmGhTqwE8C4 
grdjvJ0w5UsAVoOH7v8HQ",
     "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],
     "vicinity" : "37 Bank St, Pyrmont"
  },
  {
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -33.867591,
           "lng" : 151.201196
        }
     },
     "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/
 place_api/icons/travel_agent- 71.png",
     "id" : "a97f9fb468bcd26b68a23072a55af82d4b325e0d",
     "name" : "Australian Cruise Group",
     "opening_hours" : {
        "open_now" : true
     },
     "photos" : [
        {
           "height" : 242,
           "html_attributions" : [],
           "photo_reference" : 


 "CnRnAAAABjeoPQ7NUU3pDitV4Vs0BgP1FLhf_iCgStUZUr4Z
 uNqQnc5k43jbvjKC2hTGM8SrmdJYyOyx 


RO3D2yutoJwVC4Vp_dzckkjG35L6LfMm5sjrOr6uyOtr2PNC
p1xQylx6vhdcpW8yZjBZCvVsjNajLBIQ- 
z4ttAMIc8EjEZV7LsoFgRoU6OrqxvKCnkJGb9F16W57iIV4LuM",
           "width" : 200
        }
     ],
     "place_id" : "ChIJrTLr-GyuEmsRBfy61i59si0",
     "reference" : "CoQBeQAAAFvf12y8veSQMdIMmAXQmus1zqkgKQ- 
O2KEX0Kr47rIRTy6HNsyosVl0CjvEBulIu_cujrSOgICdcxNioFDHtAxXBhqeR- 

8xXtm52Bp0lVwnO3LzLFY3jeo8WrsyIwNE1kQlG
uWA4xklpOknHJuRXSQJVheRlYijOHSgsBQ35mOcEhC 
5IpbpqCMe82yR136087wZGhSziPEbooYkHLn9e5njOTuBprcfVw",
     "types" : [ "travel_agency", "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],
     "vicinity" : "32 The Promenade, King Street Wharf 5, Sydney"
  }
],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/processurl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Show List"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="312dp"
    android:layout_height="466dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/processurl"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.26" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

Uses Permission in Manifest---->

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

---

Dependencies in build.gradle:---->

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'

}
```

Logcat(error):--->

```
2020-08-21 13:55:39.111 31636-31636/com.example.experimentmaps W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: 
End of input at character 1 of {
2020-08-21 13:55:39.112 31636-31636/com.example.experimentmaps W/System.err:     at 
org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:460)
2020-08-21 13:55:39.112 31636-31636/com.example.experimentmaps W/System.err:     at 
org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:101)
2020-08-21 13:55:39.112 31636-31636/com.example.experimentmaps W/System.err:     at 
org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:371)
2020-08-21 13:55:39.113 31636-31636/com.example.experimentmaps W/System.err:     at 
org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:104)
2020-08-21 13:55:39.113 31636-31636/com.example.experimentmaps W/System.err:     at 
org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:165)
2020-08-21 13:55:39.113 31636-31636/com.example.experimentmaps W/System.err:     at 
org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:182)
2020-08-21 13:55:39.113 31636-31636/com.example.experimentmaps W/System.err:     at 
com.example.experimentmaps.MainActivity$DownloadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:89)
2020-08-21 13:55:39.113 31636-31636/com.example.experimentmaps W/System.err:     at 
com.example.experimentmaps.MainActivity$DownloadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:54)
2020-08-21 13:55:39.113 31636-31636/com.example.experimentmaps W/System.err:     at 
android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:771)
2020-08-21 13:55:39.113 31636-31636/com.example.experimentmaps W/System.err:     at 
android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:199)
2020-08-21 13:55:39.113 31636-31636/com.example.experimentmaps W/System.err:     at 
android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:788)
2020-08-21 13:55:39.113 31636-31636/com.example.experimentmaps W/System.err:     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
2020-08-21 13:55:39.114 31636-31636/com.example.experimentmaps W/System.err:     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
2020-08-21 13:55:39.116 31636-31636/com.example.experimentmaps W/System.err:     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7476)
2020-08-21 13:55:39.117 31636-31636/com.example.experimentmaps W/System.err:     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2020-08-21 13:55:39.117 31636-31636/com.example.experimentmaps W/System.err:     at 
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
2020-08-21 13:55:39.117 31636-31636/com.example.experimentmaps W/System.err:     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:939)
```

With some basic knowledge of JSON, I am trying to show all the nearby places in a list, this project may contain other error(maybe), any suggestion(i mean anything wrongly written or missed) will be grateful!

Thanks in advance for helping!

please someone help ,i posted this question 10 days ago still not get any answer..

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized arrayList 2 times. 1 Globally and one locally. please check. But i dont think that will solve your issue.

Comment: sorry but i removed that extra Arraylist  and still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think JSON parsing is wrong,

Instead of ` String placesinformation = jsonObject.getString("results");

```
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(placesinformation);`
```

Try

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
```

Comment: done what u said ,but still getting the same error.

Comment: Please check json data. When ii checked there are some spaces in icon and photo reference. Copy data and check it in jsonlint.com by pasting the data over there. Then click validate. If response is valid json then there is no problem with json otherwise check the data once

Comment: I am not getting what u r trying to say. from the json reponse i used "results" array, and from all the elements of "results" array. , i  taken out all the json object whose identity is "name". to show all the names in the listview.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to Spot the problem you need to add log.d statements to show the received JSON string to Logcat after each stage, Like after receiving the string eg: before return in doInBackground(), then run your app and watch for the received result in Logcat. second, You can't write string in multi-line like what you have done to URL string, you need to write it in one line or at least use string conactenation operator '+' whenever you add new line to your string. also you can't have spaces in URL as it must contain no spaces in order to work. Third You are using string to store each char of the result stream, and this is inefficient because String is immutable in Java, and and by this you are creating a new String object for every char of your stream, so it is better to use StringBuilder to do it efficiently like this:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                HttpsURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                int responseCode = ((HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection())
                        .getResponseCode();
                Log.i("TAGf", "doInBackground: responseCode:" + responseCode);
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76");
                httpURLConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                for (String line; (line = r.readLine()) != null; ) {

                    total.append(line).append('\n');
                   
                }

                Log.i("RESULT", "result: "+total.toString());
                return total.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Error in PhoneDownloader Async Task";
            }
        }
```